# mod_rewrite serving a page from another request

Tags: php, html, apache, mod-rewrite

Hay, I'm using mod_rewrite with apache, and want URLS from

```
http://www.DOMAN.com/course/course-a/
```

to actually serve from

```
http://www.DOMAN.com/blog/course/course-a/
```

Can someone help me on this please.

Comment: This is most basic mod_rewrite use. Have your read the docs? What problem are you having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/^course\/(.*)/ /blog/course/$1 [R]
```

This should redirect anything that starts with course to the blog section